# knockoutjs template binding not working

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I have been trying all day to get some data properly formatted in a html table using knockoutjs.

I wan't to show a list of documents in a html table where the document title in the first field should have a link to the actual file.

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jenrud/SCUWc/

Can anybody tell me why it's not working?

Also if you could give some advise as to how I can paginate and filter the datatable using jquery or some other technology would be great.

Thanks
Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SCUWc/2/

Couple of things:

1. You need to make sure that jQuery templates loads BEFORE Knockout as KO does some tests during its initialization to see if jQuery templates are loaded
2. If you are going to use jQuery templates, you need to pull the latest version and use that. (KO was throwing an error that you didn't have the latest)
3. I switched your template from using `{{each}}` to using KO's `foreach`. Its a bit more intelligent about not re-rendering all of your data should an item change

Comment: Thanks Eric, I seen my failings now. I was hoping though to get some way to iterate over the table rows so I could apply a css class to alternate rows. Thanks again. /Jens

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SCUWc/3/  thats a bit closer to your original with the different row colors. You could also add an 'index' property to your `document` object and use it with KO native templates

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code to

```
<tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'documentsTemplate', foreach: documents}">
```

Answer (score -1):

KnockoutJS 2.0 doesn't work with jquery.tmpl. You should use the new each binding in 2.0.

But if you must use jquery.tmpl, you can reference KnockoutJS 1.2 and see it working.

Comment: -1, http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_6_using_jquerytmpl_an_external_stringbased_template_engine